# MSSQL database query translate given values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have simple MSSQL query:

```
SELECT tw_todo as td FROM tw__work
```

where td gives me bit values like T or F (True/False).

Is there a way to translate this values to 1 or 0 inside this query?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN tw_todo = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as td FROM tw__work
```

Try above query.

Here I had used **`CASE WHEN`** which will convert **`'T' and 'F'`** to **`1 and 0`**

Comment: Thanks! I will check it at home and give feedback!

Comment: Well done. In my case 'T' was 'true' but Your piece of query gives me right direction. Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE tw_todo WHEN 'T' THEN 1 WHEN 'F' THEN 0 ELSE 0/0 END as td FROM tw__work
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it at home and give feedback!

Comment: Well done. Good attempt to my question. @sagar code is slighty better. Thanks mate! :)